# Creating a new variable while looping over rows in a tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I have been delving into the whole tidyverse ecosystem (just a little bit) and I have been wondering how to solve the follwing problem with it.
More in general, I have been wondering how to write custom functions in transmute which deal with (loops over) rows

My problem: I would like to compute a distance metric between the last row of my dataset and all other rows. Afterwards, I would like to add the vector with the distance metrics to my data.

Here is a minimum reproducible example of what I am trying to do in a non-tidyverse way

```
data(iris)
mydata <- iris[, -5]

mydata$distance <- sapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(j){
  dist(rbind(mydata[nrow(mydata), ], mydata[j, ]))})
```

This works and gives me what I need.

However, my tidyverse attempt for a solution is failing and I have been banging my head on this problem - would appreciate the help!

```
mydata <- select(iris, -Species)
mydata %>% transmute(function(x){
 for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    dist(rbind(x[i, ],x[nrow(x), ]))
 }
})
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to add the vector to your data, you'd want to use `mutate` rather than `transmute`. `transmute` just gives you back the single result while mutate adds the column to the data.

You original function works as well, but if you want to go full `tidyverse` you'd be swapping out `sapply` for `map_dbl` (from `purrr`), and `rbind` for `bind_rows`

```
mydata <- select(iris, -Species) %>% 
  mutate(distance = map_dbl(1:nrow(mydata), ~dist(bind_rows(mydata[nrow(mydata), ], mydata[.x, ]))))
```

Comment: thank you very much, Jake! I didn't know about purrr, I will look into it! cheers